# How to link statically two subprojects with main project when subrojects call dynamically libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I have project with two subdirectories( projects ) inside my directory with own CMakeLists.txt files like

```
main_dir:
   CMakeLists.txt
   src/

   dir_one/
      CMakeLists.txt
      src/

   dir_two/
      CMakeLists.txt
      src/
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like

```
.....
    target_link_libraries (
        main
        /usr/lib/dir_one.so
        /usr/lib/dir_two.so
    )
```

How to make that dir_one and dir_two are builded static inside main build, to easily deploy ?
( To link statically with main ).

Comment: Don't add paths to `.so` on linker command-line. If the libraries are generated by other projects, just add the projects and let CMake use appropriate flags. If not, use appropriate `-l` flag. The library locating magic is somewhat fragile and this is the standard way.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the project name in the target_link_libraries rather than the .so file. CMake will set all the dependencies correctly, and link the output of them.

```
target_link_libraries(main dir_one dir_two)
```

Quote from the doc:

> If a library name matches that of another target in the project a dependency will automatically be added in the build system to make sure the library being linked is up-to-date before the target links. Item names starting with -, but not -l or -framework, are treated as linker flags.